# Model is showing from inside

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know almost everybody had this but I just can't find the answer.
I think it's something to do with culling but I don't know how to disable it.
It's about the Model showing from the inside. (I made the model in Blender)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unity standard shader has backface-culling enabled by default.

Two reasons why you could see the inside of your model:

1. You have modeled an actual inside of your model, so that the are face with the normal direction pointing to the insight
2. You are using a custom shader that allows double-sided rendering (backface-culling disabled)